# add axes back to figure in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried the following example, but keeps getting error message:

```
raise **ValueError("The Subplot must have been created in "
```

ValueError: The Subplot must have been created in the present figure**
from line `"fig.add_subplot(ax2)  # add ax1 back to the figure"`

Also, `"ax1.remove()  # delete ax1 from the figure"` does not seem to work either. Many thanks.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

fig.add_subplot(231)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, 1)  # equivalent but more general

fig.add_subplot(232, frameon=False)  # subplot with no frame
fig.add_subplot(233, projection='polar')  # polar subplot
fig.add_subplot(234, sharex=ax1)  # subplot sharing x-axis with ax1
fig.add_subplot(235, facecolor="red")  # red subplot

ax1.remove()  # delete ax1 from the figure
fig.add_subplot(ax1)  # add ax1 back to the figure


plt.show()
```

Comment: After remove, you can add a subplot in same position using `fig.add_subplot(231)`

Comment: Thanks, but why it can't be "ax1" but "231" in add_subplot()? Also, I kinda figured out that why "ax1.remove()" does not work because subplot(234) shared the same x axis with it, so it might have blocked the removal action, but not 100% sure.